# toString float number in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In below snippet, how can I show message

```
Min value is 0.00000001.
```

rather than

```
Min value is 1e-8
```

```js
var minValue = 0.00000001;

var message =  "Min value is " +  minValue.toString();

var content = $('p#content').text(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="content"></p>
```

Comment: why are u doing toString() ?

Comment: it's typescript actually, datatype is number

Comment: isnt it just print?

Comment: yeah, I thought javascript automatically casted to string in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) or use a string instead of Number.

```js
var minValue = 0.00000001;

var message =  "Min value is " +  minValue.toFixed(8);

var content = $('p#content').text(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="content"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var minValue = "0.00000001";

var message =  "Min value is " +  minValue;

var content = $('p#content').text(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="content"></p>
```